# websockets.os is missing from kamailio source

Tags: websocket, kamailio

i can not include websockets module in kamailio there no websockets.os in kamailio source in

```
/usr/local/src/kamailio-4.0/kamailio/modules/websockets/
```

or

```
/usr/local/src/kamailio-4.0/kamailio/modules_k/websockets/
```

i try to install kamailio-4.0 from git i follow this link

http://www.kamailio.org/wiki/install/4.0.x/git[enter link description here](http://www.kamailio.org/wiki/install/4.0.x/git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you added websocket module to be compiled. It depends on libunistring and because of that it is not compiled by default.

To compile it, do:

```
make include_modules="websocket" cfg
make all
make install
```

If you need other extra module, add it to include_modules value. For example, to compile db_mysql and websocket, use:

```
make include_modules="db_mysql websocket" cfg
```

The alternative is to edit the file modules.lst and add the extra modules to "include_modules" variable. If you don't have the file modules.lst, do:

```
make cfg
```

After editing the file, do the usual "make all; make install".